# How to get unknown file path - the extension path - using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, fs, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop an extension for VSCode and I need to search for the exact file path where my extension is saved. I've tried this code:

```
var text;

const directoryPath = path.join(Os.homedir(), '.vscode/extensions');
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        y2.appendLine('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    }
    for (let i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        if (files[i].startsWith("MY_EXTENSION")){
            text = files[i];
            y2.appendLine(text);
            break;
        }
    }
});
y2.appendLine(text);
```

`y2` is only an output channel I added.
The outcome of this code is:

```
undefined
MY_EXTENSION
```

If I take out the second `y2.appendLine(text)` I receive only `MY_EXTENSION` but I don't get how to make `text` global or how to modify the value of the global variable `text` inside `readdir`.

I also don't understand why it first executes `y2.appendLine(text)` and then `readdir`.

It is really important and I would be grateful to have your help!

Comment: Due to the nature of JS, it will not wait for `readdir` to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the path to your extension, use the `context` object and its properties:

`extensionPath`

> The absolute file path of the directory containing the extension.
> Shorthand notation for `ExtensionContext.extensionUri.fsPath`
> (independent of the uri scheme).

`extensionUri`

> The uri of the directory containing the extension.

From [ExtensionContext](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext).  If it is just for the purpose of storage, see @mausworks's answer about `globalStorage` or `storagePath`, ets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do there, but looking at your code it seems like you are trying to save some data for your extension in particular.

For this purpose, you probably want to use the `globalStorage` object instead.

You can learn more about it in the [Data storage section](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage) and the [ExtensionContext documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext).

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in a function like this:

```js
function searchExt() {
    const directoryPath = path.join(Os.homedir(), '.vscode/extensions');
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, (err, files) => {
        let text = null;
        if (err) {
            y2.appendLine(`Unable to scan directory: ${err}`);
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if (files[i].startsWith('MY_EXTENSION')) {
                    text = files[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return text;
    });
}

const searchResult = searchExt();
```